# Recargar página al seleccionar o deseleccionar checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp, checkbox

Tengo una app en `C# ASP` que dependiendo de si el `chekbox` esta seleccionado muestra una consulta a la base de datos u otra.

Bien. Eso funciona porque si pongo por defecto un valor u otro del `checkbox` funciona perfectamente.

Ahora quisiera que cuando pulse el `Checkbox` recargue la página manteniendo la selección. Como podría hacerlo? 
`Jquery`?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Edito:

```
if (mostrarusuarioscheck.Checked==true)
    {
        string cadConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gestionTienda"].ConnectionString;

        MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(cadConexion);

        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("select nick from usuarios where tipo='gestor' or tipo='supergestor'", conexion);
        MySqlDataReader lector;
        Usuario nuevo;

        string tipo_usuario = (string)Session["TipoUsuario"];

        if (tipo_usuario != null)
        {
            switch (tipo_usuario)
            {
                case "pl":
                    comando.CommandText = "select nick from usuarios where tipo='gestor' or tipo='supergestor'";
                    break;
            }
        }

  else
    {
        string cadConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gestionTienda"].ConnectionString;

        MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(cadConexion);

        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("select nick from usuarios where nick like 'subscripcion%' or tipo='suscrito' or tipo='subscriptor'", conexion);
        MySqlDataReader lector;
        Usuario nuevo;

        string tipo_usuario = (string)Session["TipoUsuario"];

        if (tipo_usuario != null)
        {
            switch (tipo_usuario)
            {
                case "pl":
                    comando.CommandText = "select nick from usuarios where tipo='registroQr'";
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Falta parte del segundo código pero bueno, para que veais la idea.

Comment: Puedes hacer algo así, con jquery [checkbox checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)

Comment: Que has probado? Pon el código para que podamos ver como aplicarlo y para complementar mas la pregunta.

Comment: He visto esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery pero no he podido solucionarlo. Lo que tengo es un if en C# que hace una consulta a la base de datos dependiendo de lo que esté seleccionado. Si pongo el valor del chekbox en true or false de forma manual, carga la página de forma correcta dependiendo el if, pero claro, eso no es lo que quiero. Quiero que cuando seleccione o deseleccione, se cargue toda la página normalmente, manteniendo el valor del checkbox.

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y poner el código para que nos sea más fácil ayudarte?

Comment: Añado esto aquí porque no se porque no sale arriba:  <asp:CheckBox ID="mostrarusuarioscheck" checked="false" runat="server" />

Comment: el codigo que nos muestras en que contexto esta ubicado? o sea en que evento del webform

Comment: Analizando lo que explicas la verdad no entiendo, la seleccion del checkbox si es un control de asp.net se mantiene automaticamente no tienes que hacer nada